# Why am I getting different results when using Arrays.fill vs. manually making the list?

Tags: java, arrays, static

I'm not that familiar with all the behavior of Java so sorry if I'm making an obvious mistake.  Basically I'm making a program that given a list of items & range it calculates percentages that would could be used to include all items. For example, if you have a basket of fruit and want to put Apple, Pears, Peaches with no item less than 20% and no item greater than 60% the program will tell you.

In order to do that I have a list that has the lower bound(min. percentage) and the higher bound(max. percentage). My problem is when I create the list manually it seems to work(using the above example, 3 items, 20-60 range I get 41 items), but when I use `Arrays.fill` I get 882 results(which is wrong because its including 0's and not respecting the lower bound).

I'm not sure what the problem is..I looked into `Arrays.fill` and it seems to do what I want, I also listed the items in the list in both cases(manual vs. Arrays.fill) and they both look the same.

Here's the differences(working version):

```
static final String[] names = new String[] {"apples", "pears", "peach" }; //test
static final int[] low_bound = new int[] {20,20, 20}; //this allows us to invididually set the range of each item
static final int[] high_bound = new int[] {60,60, 20};
```

Not working version:

```
static final String[] names = new String[] {"apples", "pears", "peach" }; 
static int[] low_bound = new int[names.length];
static int[] high_bound = new int[names.length];
//then in the main method
Arrays.fill(low_bound, 20); //fills the min list with default value
Arrays.fill(high_bound, 60); //fills the max list with default value
```

Why are the results different? These are the only changes between the working version and broken version. I want to use large lists and don't want to enter the data manually(but I like the flexibility of making individual ranges if I want), am I using Arrays.fill wrong or some other rookie mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing Apples and Oranges, for your static test, the `high_bound` values are `{60, 60, 20}` but when you use `Arrays.fill()`, you are setting it to {60, 60, 60}.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense because Array.fill code is:

```
    public static void fill(long[] a, long val) {
        for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++)
            a[i] = val;
    }
```

The resulting array would look exactly like the static initialization.

Also, I ran your code with both initialization and got the same result: "total size of results are 882"